# Create a Windows Form Control out of WebView2

Tags: c#, windows, controls, webview2

Trying to create a windows form control to open a URL in the Edge Browser. Wrote the below code  and I am trying to debug the control with windows form app. Any help how to resolve this error?:

> `System.DllNotFoundException`: 'Unable to load DLL '`WebView2Loader.dll`': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from `HRESULT`: `0x8007007E`)

Using below versions for development:

- WebView2 version - 1.0.2151.40
- Runtime version - 119.0.2151.97

```
private async void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        CoreWebView2Environment environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync();
        CoreWebView2Controller controller = await environment.CreateCoreWebView2ControllerAsync(_ParentWindowHandle);
        webview = controller.CoreWebView2;
        //webview =environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(URLtoOpen,)
        webview.Navigate("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/");

    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to debug the control to test the control...however getting the error Unable to load DLL 'WebView2Loader.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)...looking of insights on how to get this resolved

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#files-to-ship-with-the-app): "The WebView2Loader code needs to be shipped with the app. This can be done by statically linking WebView2Loader.lib into the app binaries, or by including the WebView2Loader.dll that matches the app's architecture." It looks like you used the DLL approach but forgot to include the DLL in your distribution.

Comment: I am using Visual C++ and I had to add the code into the project files directly. Not the way I formally did it. I suggest you visit the WebView2 samples repository and down the one for your platform and look at the configuration.